# calling a __thiscall DLL function from VC++ code

Tags: visual-c++, reverse-engineering, dllimport, class-constructors

I have a DLL file to get reverse-engineered and I would like to call one of its functions (i.e. a class constructor) directly in my x86 C++ code. The reason is that I have no clue what the structure of the class would be and I have no header file as well. The `calling convention` of this function is `__thiscall`. I am interested to get access to the `this` pointer from my code and from what I have read in **MSDN** page, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/thiscall?view=msvc-170) , `this` pointer is located in `ecx` register.

> The Microsoft-specific __thiscall calling convention is used on C++ class member functions on the x86 architecture.
>
> ...
>
> The this pointer is passed via register ECX, and not on the stack.

If I want to get five different objects from five times calling the loaded function, I expect to get five different `this` pointer, but from my code below, they are all the same value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    typedef void (__thiscall* CTOR)(void);

    HMODULE dll = LoadLibraryA(R"(MYDLL.dll)");
    if (!dll)
        std::cout << "can not load dll error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    else
    {       
        void* default_ctor_this_pointer = ::operator new(4);

        if (default_ctor_this_pointer)
        {
            for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                std::memset(default_ctor_this_pointer, 0, 4);

                CTOR default_ctor = (CTOR)(GetProcAddress(dll, "??0TestClass@@QAE@XZ"));
                std::cout << "\t[+]TestClass::TestClass() = 0x" << default_ctor << " --> error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
                std::cout << "\t\t[-]this_pointer before call: 0x" << std::hex << *(unsigned*)default_ctor_this_pointer << std::dec << std::endl;       
                _asm {mov ecx, default_ctor_this_pointer};
                default_ctor();
                _asm {mov default_ctor_this_pointer, ecx};
                std::cout << "\t\t[-]this_pointer after call: 0x" << std::hex << *(unsigned*)default_ctor_this_pointer << std::dec << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and this is what I get as output

```
[+]TestClass::TestClass() = 0x62995440 --> error: 0
    [-]this_pointer before call: 0x0
    [-]this_pointer after call: 0x62a7d8d8
[+]TestClass::TestClass() = 0x62995440 --> error: 0
    [-]this_pointer before call: 0x0
    [-]this_pointer after call: 0x62a7d8d8
[+]TestClass::TestClass() = 0x62995440 --> error: 0
    [-]this_pointer before call: 0x0
    [-]this_pointer after call: 0x62a7d8d8
[+]TestClass::TestClass() = 0x62995440 --> error: 0
    [-]this_pointer before call: 0x0
    [-]this_pointer after call: 0x62a7d8d8
[+]TestClass::TestClass() = 0x62995440 --> error: 0
    [-]this_pointer before call: 0x0
    [-]this_pointer after call: 0x62a7d8d8
```

I expected to retrieve five different `this` values, but as you can see they are the same value. Did I do the procedure the wrong way?

**Edited->** after what Ext3h suggested, I changed the code as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    typedef void (__thiscall* CTOR)(void);

    HMODULE dll = LoadLibraryA(R"(MYDLL.dll)");
    if (!dll)
        std::cout << "can not load dll error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    else
    {       
        void* default_ctor_this_pointer = ::operator new(4096);

        if (default_ctor_this_pointer)
        {
            for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                std::memset(default_ctor_this_pointer, 0, 4096);

                CTOR default_ctor = (CTOR)(GetProcAddress(dll, "??0TestClass@@QAE@XZ"));
                std::cout << "\t[+]TestClass::TestClass() = 0x" << default_ctor << " --> error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
                std::cout << "\t\t[-]this_pointer before call: 0x" << std::hex << *(unsigned*)default_ctor_this_pointer << std::dec << std::endl;       
                _asm {mov ecx, default_ctor_this_pointer};
                default_ctor();
                _asm {mov default_ctor_this_pointer, eax};
                std::cout << "\t\t[-]this_pointer after call: 0x" << std::hex << *(unsigned*)default_ctor_this_pointer << std::dec << std::endl;
                std::cout << "\t\t\t[-]";
                for(std::size_t j = 0; j < 10: j++)
                {
                    std::cout << "0x" <, std::hex << ((unsigned)(default_ctor_this_pointer))[j] << " " << std::dec;
                } std::cout << "\n";
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
    [+]TestClass::TestClass = 0x62955C40 --> error: 0
        [-]this_pointer before call: 0x0
        [-]this_pointer after call: 0x62ab2380
            [-]0x62ab2380 0x62ab0160 0x0 0x62ab23ac 0x940c70 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0
    [+]TestClass::TestClass = 0x62955C40 --> error: 0
        [-]this_pointer before call: 0x0
        [-]this_pointer after call: 0x62ab2380
            [-]0x62ab2380 0x62ab0160 0x0 0x62ab23ac 0x940798 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0
    [+]TestClass::TestClass = 0x62955C40 --> error: 0
        [-]this_pointer before call: 0x0
        [-]this_pointer after call: 0x62ab2380
            [-]0x62ab2380 0x62ab0160 0x0 0x62ab23ac 0x940950 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0
    [+]TestClass::TestClass = 0x62955C40 --> error: 0
        [-]this_pointer before call: 0x0
        [-]this_pointer after call: 0x62ab2380
            [-]0x62ab2380 0x62ab0160 0x0 0x62ab23ac 0x940900 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0
    [+]TestClass::TestClass = 0x62955C40 --> error: 0
        [-]this_pointer before call: 0x0
        [-]this_pointer after call: 0x62ab2380
            [-]0x62ab2380 0x62ab0160 0x0 0x62ab23ac 0x940978 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call the constructor with a mere 4 byte allocation - you will need to have provided sufficient storage space at the address pointed to by `ecx` to begin with. For all you know, the constructor may have failed for any reason.

---

If the construction was successful, you should find the address of the constructed object in register `eax`. The contents of `ecx` are undefined, it's a volatile register (not callee saved!).

Take a close look at a minimal example of a `__thiscall` constructor invocation (https://godbolt.org/z/zhfEexcEE):

```
class Foo {
    public:
    __thiscall Foo() : x(nullptr) {
    }
    void* x;
};
```

The assembly is mostly self-explanatory:

```
_this$ = -4                                   ; size = 4
Foo::Foo(void) PROC                           ; Foo::Foo, COMDAT
        // `ebp` and `esp` are non-volatile, and have to be saved by the callee.
        push    ebp
        mov     ebp, esp
        // Compiler quirk - MSVC writes `this` to the stack ... twice.
        push    ecx
        mov     DWORD PTR _this$[ebp], ecx
        // Member initialization
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR _this$[ebp]
        mov     DWORD PTR [eax], 0
        // Here comes the ret val
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR _this$[ebp]
        // Restore non-volatile registers
        mov     esp, ebp
        pop     ebp
        ret     0
Foo::Foo(void) ENDP                           ; Foo::Foo
```

---

```
_asm {mov default_ctor_this_pointer, eax};
std::cout << "\t\t[-]this_pointer after call: 0x" << std::hex << *(unsigned*)default_ctor_this_pointer << std::dec << std::endl;
```

Mind that this is not `this` you are printing, but the *content* at the address of `this`.

```
[+]TestClass::TestClass() = 0x62995440 --> error: 0
    [-]*this_pointer after call: 0x62a7d8d8
```

Judging by the value it is a pointer after-all, but some static data from the same module as the constructor.

Most likely a vtable pointer as you've constructed a class with virtual methods.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I changed the code by these two exchanges. ```void* default_ctor_this_pointer = ::operator new(4096); std::memset(default_ctor_this_pointer, 0, 4096);``` and ```mov default_ctor_this_pointer, eax```. But the result is still the same as before.

Comment: @ImanAbdollahzadeh I hope you mean `mov default_ctor_this_pointer, eax` - because `ecx` is volatile and has no meaning after the constructor returns.

Comment: Yes. I edited my mistake.

Comment: @ImanAbdollahzadeh Also mind that you are looking at the *content* of the memory at `default_ctor_this_pointer` - so that `0x62995440` is not a pointer - it's the content of that class's storage.

Well, it possibly *is* a pointer, but likely a vtable ptr...

Comment: I added and edited some modified code as well as some extra logging to STDOUT to see the content of the memory containing ```this``` pointer. As you can see only the 5th element differs for each call to the constructor.

Comment: @ImanAbdollahzadeh Why would that surprise you?  The only way you can expect varying data for calling the same constructor, is if the constructor has non-deterministic parts like allocating memory of its own. Just take your debugger already and take a peek at the pointers you see. You'll be able to identify what's there quickly.

Comment: I expect to see 5 various ```this``` pointers because I created 5 objects of class. Whatever is inside the buffer pointed by ```this``` would be interesting, but am I right?

Comment: You already provided the `this` pointer in `ecx` (and you've provided always the same, 5 times, every time overwriting the previous instance), and you are already looking at the data poined to by `this` - not at `this` itself. So you are already looking at the "interesting stuff".

Comment: Fair enough. I got the point. An extra inquiry. The content of ```this``` show basically 16 bytes unchanged and only 4 bytes (a DWORD probably) varying. As such 16 bytes are statically defined and only 4 bytes depend on each instantiation. Right?